How to uniquely identify a given set amongst the other partially overlapping sets just by using combination of include list and the exclude list
Example usage
setts = {

    'Set_A': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],

    'Set_B': [10, 11, 12, 13],

    'Set_C': [10, 11, 15],

    'Set_D': [15, 16, 17],

    'Set_E': [10, 11, 12, 14]

}

The output should be:
Set_A: Includes = {13, 14}, Excludes = set()
Set_B: Includes = {13}, Excludes = {14}
Set_C: Includes = {10, 15} or {11, 15}, Excludes = set()
Set_D: Includes = {16} or {17}, Excludes = set()
Set_E: Includes = {14}, Excludes = {13}
Note: For Set_E, just having 14 won't be enough. We need to exclude 13 as well. This rules out Set_A, and we remain with a single unique Set_E.
For Set_A, having includes = {13,14} is enough as no other sets have 13 & 14 combination. If we were to add {10,11,12} it would be redundant.
How can I systematically approach this problem using Python Code keeping in mind that the sum of elements in both inlcudes and excludes should be minimum?
I wrote the Python Code on Visual Studio 2019 as follows but it was giving not correct output.
from itertools import combinations

def find_unique_signals(setts):
    includes = {}
    excludes = {}

    # Convert Setts to sets for easier manipulation
    setts_sets = {k: set(v) for k, v in setts.items()}

    # Step 1: Find unique includes
    for sett, numbers in setts_sets.items():
        unique_numbers = numbers.copy()
        for other_sett, other_numbers in setts_sets.items():
            if sett != other_sett:
                unique_numbers -= other_numbers
        if unique_numbers:
            includes[sett] = unique_numbers
            excludes[sett] = set()
        else:
            includes[sett] = set()
            excludes[sett] = set()

    # Step 2: Find minimal combinations of includes and excludes for non-unique cases
    for sett, numbers in setts_sets.items():
        if not includes[sett]:
            min_combination = None
            min_length = float('inf')

            for r in range(1, len(numbers) + 1):
                for comb in combinations(numbers, r):
                    comb_set = set(comb)
                    unique = True

                    for other_sett, other_numbers in setts_sets.items():
                        if other_sett != sett:
                            if comb_set <= other_numbers:
                                unique = False
                                break

                    if unique and len(comb_set) < min_length:
                        min_combination = comb_set
                        min_length = len(comb_set)

            if min_combination:
                includes[sett] = min_combination
                excludes[sett] = numbers - min_combination

    return includes, excludes

# Example usage
setts = {
   'Set_A': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   'Set_B': [10, 11, 12, 13],
   'Set_C': [10, 11, 15],
   'Set_D': [15, 16, 17],
   'Set_E': [10, 11, 12, 14]
}

includes, excludes = find_unique_signals(setts)

for sett in setts:
    print(f"{sett}: Includes = {includes.get(sett, set())}, Excludes = {excludes.get(sett, set())}")

# The output of the above code is as follows which is not correct.
# Set_A: Includes = {13,14}, Excludes = {10,11,12} 
# Set_B: Includes = set(), Excludes = set() 
# Set_C: Includes = {10,15}, Excludes = {11} 
# Set_D: Includes = {16,17}, Excludes = set() 
# Set_E: Includes = set(), Excludes = set()

Please help me correct the code so that I get expected output mentioned previously.

It's not clear what you are asking. What specifically does it mean for Set_A to "include" {13, 14}. It seems like it also includes {10, 11, 12}. What makes 13 and 14 special?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Mark, with the minimum no. of elements, we need to uniquely identify a DBC. So, for Set_A If I were to include {10,11,12} then other sets like Set_B, Set_E also come into picture. But if I just say {13,14}, then only Set_A contains these two numbers. So, with just 2 numbers, I am able to uniquely identify Set_A

@DevVerma -- Do not tag this as dsa,  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

I wrote the Python Code as follows but it was giving not correct output. -- What is a debugger?.

@PaulMcKenzie, I had used Visual Studio 2019 for running the Python code

The output is getting generated with no errors or warnings. Just that wrong output is generated for the sets' inlcudes/excludes list. Therefore, the code must be corrected to give expected result.

One efficient approach is to iteratively filter the remaining lists by either an item to include or an item to exclude, whichever leaves the least number of lists:
from operator import and_, sub

def get_uniquely_identifying_sets(sets):
    sets_with_item = {}
    for name, items in sets.items():
        for item in items:
            sets_with_item.setdefault(item, set()).add(name)
    result = {}
    for name, items in sets.items():
        includes = set(items)
        excludes = sets_with_item.keys() - includes
        remaining = sets.keys() - {name}
        while remaining:
            item, action = min(
                [(item, and_) for item in includes] +
                [(item, sub) for item in excludes],
                key=lambda t: len(t[1](remaining, sets_with_item[t[0]]))
            )
            new_remaining = action(remaining, sets_with_item[item])
            if remaining == new_remaining:
                raise ValueError(f"Can't uniquely identify {name}")
            remaining = new_remaining
            (includes, excludes)[action == sub].remove(item)
            result.setdefault(name, (set(), set()))[action == sub].add(item)
    return result

so that:
sets = {
    'Set_A': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    'Set_B': [10, 11, 12, 13],
    'Set_C': [10, 11, 15],
    'Set_D': [15, 16, 17],
    'Set_E': [10, 11, 12, 14]
}
for name, (includes, excludes) in get_uniquely_identifying_sets(sets).items():
    print(f'{name}: Includes = {includes}, Excludes = {excludes}')

outputs:
Set_A: Includes = {13, 14}, Excludes = set()
Set_B: Includes = {13}, Excludes = {14}
Set_C: Includes = {10, 15}, Excludes = set()
Set_D: Includes = {16}, Excludes = set()
Set_E: Includes = {14}, Excludes = {13}

Demo: https://ideone.com/5QSMy1

Does this always produce optimal results?

@blhsing, the output result is coming as per expectation. Just my one more requirement was if there are more than one unique numbers In a set then all those unique signals be mentioned in another list let's say unique list and the includes & excludes will be empty. But anyways, the major bulk algorithm has been provided with your beautifully written code. Thanks for the support

@DevVerma But you said "should be minimum". Is that no longer a requirement?

@blhsing I should have mentioned in the question body properly, my mistake. The scene is that if there is no unique number found for a particular set, then the includes + excludes members should be minimum. Incase, if there is even a single unique number that gets found, then dig deeper and find all those unique numbers and put the output In a separate set unique_numbers. Currently with your code, if excludes is empty and includes has just one element, then that means we have the opportunity to dig deeper to find more such unique numbers. That's how we can proceed further, I suppose. Thanks

@DevVerma To be clear: What I'm talking about are sets like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 5], [0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 4], [0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 5], [0, 4, 6], [0, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], where this code produces Includes = {2, 3, 4}, Excludes = set() for the first set instead of the better Includes = {0, 1}, Excludes = set().

@blhsing for the first set you are correct, {0,1} in Includes is sufficient because no other sets has 0 and 1 combined. Suppose had there been a set on top of yours like [2,5,7,8,9] then for this set includes and excludes will be empty and unique_numbers will contain all the unique numbers another one of which are not found in any other sets - {7,8,9}.
